# ConstraintViolationException deploying an application to Glassfish in JavaEE

Tags: sql, database, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have the following "Administrator" Entity constructor:

```
public Administrator(String username, String password, String name, String email) {
        super(username, password, name, email, 2);
}
```

This inherits from the following class with the following constraints:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected int id;
@Column(unique = true)
protected String username;
@NotNull
protected String password;
@NotNull
protected String name;
@NotNull
private int type;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
        + "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@"
        + "(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
        message = "{invalid.email}")
protected String email;

public ApplicationUser() {
}

public ApplicationUser(String username, String password, String name, String email, int type) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.type = type;
}
```

So there's absolutely nothing being violated when I create a new Administrator in my ConfigBean, using this method:

```
//AdministratorBean
public void createAdministrator(String username, String password, String name, String email) {
    Administrator administrator = new Administrator(username, password, name, email);
    em.persist(administrator);
}

//ConfigBean
administratorBean.createAdministrator("admin123", "passpass", "Someguy", "some@guy.com");
```

But when I deploy the application it throws the following exception (and yes, I have tried undeploying, redeploying and rebuilding to no effect):

```
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AdministratorBean, method: public void beans.AdministratorBean.createAdministrator(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Warning:   javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
(...)
«
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
```

In some other instances of deployment I get a SQL constraint error. How can I fix this?

[EDIT] - Full stack trace of the error as request:

```
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AdministratorBean, method: public void beans.AdministratorBean.createAdministrator(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Warning:   javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:662)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy342.createAdministrator(Unknown Source)
    at beans.__EJB31_Generated__AdministratorBean__Intf____Bean__.createAdministrator(Unknown Source)
    at beans.ConfigBean.postDeploy(ConfigBean.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2014)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:468)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:647)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory.
```

Comment: You should add the cause of the error message stack trace (the `(...)`).

Comment: I just edited the question with it

Comment: Are you using transaction-type JTA?

Comment: Apparently I am:
<persistence-unit name="dae-pharmacy-managementPU" transaction-type="JTA">
I'm a complete begginer before anything

Comment: OK, did you try restarting the server before redeploying?

Comment: Yes I did. Oddly enough I just redeployed and now it says, the PharmacyBean is violating constraints, because there's not an Administrator to be found.

Comment: Then you should add this exception stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I will do another question if you don't mind

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768622/cant-get-correct-id-of-an-entity-in-configbean-java-ee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping the glassfish server, deleting the nb-derby folder contents and redeploying the application seemed to work. It's a glassfish bug.